# Save a df in XLSM file sheet without loosing images and other formatting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I have a `Main.xlsm` file and a `df` . I want to save the complete values of df in new sheet (called `Output`) in the `Main.xlsm` file without loosing any formatting in the .xlsm file.

In the Main.xlsm file I have a sheet which has certain images, certain merged cells etc.

**My code**:

```py
output_file_name = "Main.xlsm"
output_intermin_path = r"C:\Users"
output_path = "%s\\%s" % (output_intermin_path,output_file_name)

book = load_workbook(output_path, keep_vba = True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_path, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Output')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

The above code works well, but the problem is I loose the images and certain cell merges I had to make it fancy. When I run this code I loose all these things!!

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) and export all images.

```
pip install Pillow
```

Then from the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#inserting-an-image):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 'You should see three logos below'

# create an image
img = Image('logo.png')

# add to worksheet and anchor next to cells
ws.add_image(img, 'A1')
wb.save('logo.xlsx')
```

Source code:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/drawing/image.html#Image